# Memurai Developer Sentinel as service won't register

Tags: memurai

Has anyone had success in getting Memurai to run as a service as a Sentinel?  Following the [instructions from their site](https://docs.memurai.com/en/windows-service), 
`memurai.exe --service-install --service-name "memurai-sentinel" --sentinel memurai-sentinel.conf` 
results in 
`sentinel directive while not in sentinel mode`
even with the sentinel flag being present. Cutting out the service flags, it will run as a sentinel without issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Memurai team just released version 2.0.1 which fixes the Memurai Sentinel running as a service issue. Please visit https://www.memurai.com/get-memurai to get the lasted Developer build.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a fix by the Memurai Team in the next release.
Edit: This has been fixed in the Memurai 2.0.1 release.

In the meanwhile, here's a workaround that uses a PowerShell script to add a sentinel service on Windows through other means:

1. Install Memurai.
2. Copy sentinel.conf to the desired sentinel working directory. Current values in the files assume C:\sentinelconf\sentinel.conf
3. Change sentinel.conf with the desired configuration. Current values assume a Redis instance will be running in the same machine in the default port.
4. Run "Windows PowerShell ISE" as an Administrator:

   1. Open sentinel_script.ps1
   2. Change the variables at the beginning of the file to the desired values.
   3. Run the script (F5)
   4. If it results in a "running scripts is disabled on this system." error:

      1. In the interactive shell run (without the quotes): 'Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned'
      2. Try running the script again (F5)
      3. In the interactive shell run (without the quotes): 'Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted'
5. Connect the sentinel using memurai-cli in the command prompt (without the quotes): 'memurai-cli -p 5000'
6. Issue command to test the sentinel (without the quotes): 'sentinel master mymaster'

Sample `sentinel.conf`:

```
# Copy this file to C:\sentinelconf\sentinel.conf
logfile "C:\sentinelconf\sentinel.log"
port 5000
sentinel monitor mymaster 127.0.0.1 6379 1
sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 60000
sentinel failover-timeout mymaster 180000
sentinel parallel-syncs mymaster 1
```

The `sentinel_script.ps1` file :

```
# Full path of installed memurai.exe
$MemuraiBinPath="C:\Program Files\Memurai\memurai.exe"
# Full path of sentinel.conf
$SentinelConfPath="C:\sentinelconf\sentinel.conf"
# Full path of sentinel.log
$SentinelLogPath="C:\sentinelconf\sentinel.log"
# Desired name of the service
$SentinelServiceName="Memurai Sentinel"


# Get Network Service credentials
$NetworkServiceCredentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE", (New-Object System.Security.SecureString))

# Create a service to start Memurai in Sentinel mode
New-Service -Name $SentinelServiceName -Credential $NetworkServiceCredentials -BinaryPathName "`"$MemuraiBinPath`" --service-run `"$SentinelConfPath`" --sentinel"

# Create a rule to give the Network Service account access to the paths.
$SentinelAccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")

# Get the path where the sentinel.conf file is located and add permissions.
$SentinelConfFolderPath = Split-Path $SentinelConfPath
$ConfPathAccessPermissions = Get-Acl $SentinelConfFolderPath
$ConfPathAccessPermissions.SetAccessRule($SentinelAccessRule)
Set-Acl $SentinelConfFolderPath $ConfPathAccessPermissions

# Get the path where the sentinel.log file is located and add permissions.
$SentinelLogFolderPath = Split-Path $SentinelLogPath
$LogPathAccessPermissions = Get-Acl $SentinelLogFolderPath
$LogPathAccessPermissions.SetAccessRule($SentinelAccessRule)
Set-Acl $SentinelLogFolderPath $LogPathAccessPermissions

# Start the Memurai Sentinel service.
Start-Service $SentinelServiceName

Write-Host "Started the $SentinelServiceName service."
```